# C++ variant or unique_ptr: move-constructor reference argument type with clang and GNU libstdc++

Tags: c++, templates, variant, clang++

Hello fellow C++ programmers!

I'm trying to write a C++ variant class to emulate a stictly-typed union without restrictions for MSVS2012 (which is lacking one from the standard). I know that there are lots of variant implementations for C++, but reinventing stuff is fun. And there is some academic interest in the underlaying problem, anyway.

Below is the code - it's a bit over-complicated to my taste due to two points:

1. That's for MSVC 2012 which lacks a number of most-crucial parts of C++11 standard for such a task, like variadic templates or constructor inheritance
2. I failed to came up with a way to make dedicated copy/move constructors without creating ambiguous overload with templated variants. I've tried to make a std::enable_if check to prevent templated constructors spawning for derived/same types as the variant itself, but it seems to prevent MSVC implicit conversion. So I've moved the check for derived class (variant itself copy/move, not an initialization by copy/move of one of the types) into helper structs.

The code below is somewhat shortened version without accessors (they are trivial anyway), some checks and namespaces, for the sake of less noise. The problem, which is explained in more detail below the code, isn't present on MSVC though (it works there surprisingly flawlessly), but happens with clang and libstdc++ STL library (the GNU implementation from gcc-4.9.2). And only if I'm trying to put unique_ptr's within the Variant and place it into the std::vector.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// A number of template tricks to emulate tuple query things still missing from MSVC2012. Omitted for clarity, nothing really special there - looping through tuples and checking types with is_conversible
#include "core_template_magic.hpp"

template <typename TypesTuple>
class Variant
{
public:
    typedef Variant<TypesTuple> VariantBase;

    template <typename T>
    struct type_of
    {
        enum { value = find_type_in_tuple<T, TypesTuple>::value };
        static_assert(value >= 0, "There is no such type in this variant");
    };

public:
    template <typename T>
    Variant(const T& value) :
        type_(get_constructor_type<T>::run(value))
    {
        construct_copy<T, 0>::run(mem_, value);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Variant(T&& value) :
        type_(get_constructor_type<T>::run(value))
    {
        construct_move<T, 0>::run(mem_, std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    ~Variant()
    {
        destroy<0>::run(mem_, type_);
    }

private:
    /* a wrapper around type_of to work around copy constructors */

    template <typename T>
    struct is_self : public std::is_base_of<VariantBase, T> {};

    template <typename T, bool is_self = is_self<T>::value>
    struct get_constructor_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct get_constructor_type<T, false>
    {
        static int run(const T&)
        {
            return type_of<T>::value;
        }

        static int run(T&&)
        {
            return type_of<T>::value;
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct get_constructor_type<T, true>
    {
        static int run(const VariantBase& other)
        {
            return other.type_;
        }

        static int run(VariantBase&& other)
        {
            return other.type_;
        }
    };

    /* a helper for the copy constructor */

    template <typename T, int i,
                int count = std::tuple_size<TypesTuple>::value,
                bool is_self = is_self<T>::value>
    struct construct_copy
    {
        static void run(char* mem, const T& other)
        {
            new (mem) T(other);
        }
    };

    // If that's an another variant of same type - find out it's type
    // and call an appropriate copy constructor
    template <typename T, int i, int count>
    struct construct_copy<T, i, count, true>
    {
        static void run(char* mem, const VariantBase& other)
        {
            typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, TypesTuple>::type E;

            if (other.type_ == i)
                new (mem) E(*reinterpret_cast<const E*>(other.mem_));
            else
                construct_copy<T, i + 1, count, true>::run(mem, other);
        }
    };

    template <typename T, int count>
    struct construct_copy<T, count, count, true>
    { static void run(char* mem, const VariantBase& other) {} };

    /* a helper for the move constructor */

    template <typename T, int i,
                int count = std::tuple_size<TypesTuple>::value,
                bool is_self = is_self<T>::value>
    struct construct_move
    {
        static void run(char* mem, T&& other)
        {
            new (mem) T(std::forward<T>(other));
        }
    };

    // If that's an another variant of same type - find out it's type
    // and call an appropriate  move constructor
    template <typename T, int i, int count>
    struct construct_move<T, i, count, true>
    {
        static void run(char* mem, VariantBase&& other)
        {
            typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, TypesTuple>::type E;

            if (other.type_ == i)
                new (mem) E(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<E*>(other.mem_)));
            else
                construct_move<T, i + 1, count, true>::run(mem, std::forward<VariantBase>(other));
        }
    };

    template <typename T, int count>
    struct construct_move<T, count, count, true>
    { static void run(char* mem, VariantBase&& other) {} };

    // A destructor helper

    template <int i, int count = std::tuple_size<TypesTuple>::value>
    struct destroy
    {
        static void run(char* mem, const int type)
        {
            typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, TypesTuple>::type T;
            if (type == i)
                reinterpret_cast<T*>(mem)->~T();
            else
                destroy<i + 1, count>::run(mem, type);
        }
    };

    template <int count>
    struct destroy<count, count>
    { static void run(char* mem, const int type) {} };

private:
    const int type_;
    char mem_[get_max_sizeof_of_types<TypesTuple>::value];
};

// example problematic usage

struct Test : public Variant<std::tuple<
    std::unique_ptr<int>,
    std::unique_ptr<bool>,
    std::unique_ptr<double>
>>
{
    using VariantBase::VariantBase;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Test> v;

    v.emplace_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));

    return 0;
}
```

So, when I'm trying to compile that on clang++-3.6.0 with libstdc++-4.9.2, I'm getting the error

```
../main.cpp:58:14: error: multiple overloads of 'run' instantiate to the same signature 'int (Test &&)'
                static int run(T&&)
                           ^
../main.cpp:31:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::get_constructor_type<Test &, false>' requested here
                type_(get_constructor_type<T>::run(value))
                      ^
../main.cpp:174:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::Variant<Test &>' requested here
        using VariantBase::VariantBase;
                           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Construct<Test, Test &>' requested here
                std::_Construct(std::__addressof(*__cur), *__first);
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:125:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
        __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:278:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:299:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<Test *, Test *, Test>' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:421:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<Test *, Test *, std::allocator<Test> >' requested here
              = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:101:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
          _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^
../main.cpp:181:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
        v.emplace_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));
          ^
../main.cpp:53:14: note: previous declaration is here
                static int run(const T&)
                           ^
../main.cpp:18:3: error: static_assert failed "There is no such type in this variant"
                static_assert(value >= 0, "There is no such type in this variant");
                ^             ~~~~~~~~~~
../main.cpp:60:11: note: in instantiation of template class 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::type_of<Test &>' requested here
                        return type_of<T>::value;
                               ^
../main.cpp:31:34: note: in instantiation of member function 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::get_constructor_type<Test &, false>::run' requested here
                type_(get_constructor_type<T>::run(value))
                                               ^
../main.cpp:174:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::Variant<Test &>' requested here
        using VariantBase::VariantBase;
                           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Construct<Test, Test &>' requested here
                std::_Construct(std::__addressof(*__cur), *__first);
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:125:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
        __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:278:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:299:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<Test *, Test *, Test>' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:421:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<Test *, Test *, std::allocator<Test> >' requested here
              = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:101:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
          _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^
../main.cpp:181:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
        v.emplace_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));
          ^
../main.cpp:120:14: error: cannot allocate reference type 'Test &' with new
                        new (mem) T(std::forward<T>(other));
                                  ^
../main.cpp:33:25: note: in instantiation of member function 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::construct_move<Test &, 0, 3, false>::run' requested here
                construct_move<T, 0>::run(mem_, std::forward<T>(value));
                                      ^
../main.cpp:174:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::Variant<Test &>' requested here
        using VariantBase::VariantBase;
                           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Construct<Test, Test &>' requested here
                std::_Construct(std::__addressof(*__cur), *__first);
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:125:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
        __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:278:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:299:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<Test *, Test *, Test>' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:421:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<Test *, Test *, std::allocator<Test> >' requested here
              = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:101:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
          _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^
../main.cpp:181:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
        v.emplace_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));
          ^
```

Note that somewhere in the middle of the trace unique_ptr disappears and is replaced with Test&. My understanding is that emplace_back works correctly and after the

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:101:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
          _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

the item was successfully constructed into the variant as it should be, but then it seems to attempt an "uninitiliazed_copy" of some kind the new item for some reason, calling the copy/move-constructor again, but with a non-const reference this time. Why emplace_back makes a copy at all?

Obviously my fabolus check for "same type" (i.e. detecting a whole-variant copy/move attempt to trigger the more complex find-out-what-type-we-are logic) fails when it receives a reference type. Well, that's logical.

Alright, I've attempted to hack-around this by placing decaying a type within the check

```
template <typename T>
struct is_self : public std::is_base_of<VariantBase, typename std::decay<T>::type> {};
```

... to no avail, though

```
../main.cpp:33:35: error: rvalue reference to type 'VariantBase' (aka 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >') cannot bind to lvalue of type 'Test'
                construct_move<T, 0>::run(mem_, std::forward<T>(value));
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../main.cpp:174:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Variant<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::unique_ptr<bool, std::default_delete<bool> >, std::unique_ptr<double, std::default_delete<double> > > >::Variant<Test &>' requested here
        using VariantBase::VariantBase;
                           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Construct<Test, Test &>' requested here
                std::_Construct(std::__addressof(*__cur), *__first);
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:125:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
        __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:278:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::uninitialized_copy<Test *, Test *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:299:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<Test *, Test *, Test>' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:421:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<Test *, Test *, std::allocator<Test> >' requested here
              = std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a
                     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:101:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
          _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^
../main.cpp:181:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >' requested here
        v.emplace_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));
          ^
../main.cpp:129:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'other' here
                static void run(char* mem, VariantBase&& other)
```

Well, that's logical too. Of course, I may implement a couple more complex checks for reference types here, but this will only increase the already complex code and, more importantly, I don't clearly understand what I'm gonna do with a lvalue reference - convert it into rvalue and process with move semantic, maybe...

So, my questions are:

1. Am I doing all this wrong? Is there any easier way, possibly by using more explicit functions? Or maybe I should use a non-qualified template types (template  Vector(T something)) and then check for constness (copy vs move), references and types?
2. What is happening within vector and what is the right way to react to such things?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is due to some weird interaction of your class and `move_if_noexcept` that caused libstdc++'s `vector` to attempt to copy your `Variant`, which in turn blows everything up. A simple hacky solution would be to mark your `T&&` constructor `noexcept`.

Comment: Well, yes - it works, thank you! I don't use exceptions anyway (and I generally don't bother with placing noexcept's and stuff), so it's something quite acceptable for me. But academic part of the question still stands - why it's happening? I guess I'll take a peek into the STL code using your direction tip.